# Accessing SMTP Mail Settings from Web.Config File by using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Need to read my SMTP email settings defined under system.net section in my web.config file.

Below is one example of SMTP email setting defined in web.config file:
(Under  Section)

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="testuser@domail.com">
<network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" port="25" userName="user” password="testPassword"/>
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

How to Access the SMTP Mail Setting by using c#

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.GetSection`

Comment: It anyone copies the example code, be careful as the double quote after user is not a standard one so will be invalid in a web.config.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the WebConfigurationManager:

```
Configuration configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

Response.Write(mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host);
```

Comment: I am trying this and it works successfully but it throws an error : "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first." Whether i am using smtp.gmail.com server and 587 port with enablessl = true.

Answer (score 10):

Just use the  `System.Net.Mail` classes to send your e-mails. It will automagically pick-up the Mail setting from your web.config.

Comment: For completeness sake, here is a link on how to actually do it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Related...If you're accessing from both a website and an application this code can come in handy.

```
Configuration config;

bool isWebApp = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId != null;

if (isWebApp)
{
    config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
}
else
{
    config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}

var mailSettings = config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
Response.Write(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp").Network.UserName)
Response.Write(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp").Network.Host)
Response.Write(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp").Network.Password)
```